# How do `git merge B --ff` (when successful) and `git reset B --hard` differ?

Tags: git

Suppose that branch `B` is straight ahead of the current branch (so that a fast-forward merge is possible).

How do doing

```
git merge B --ff
```

and doing

```
git reset B --hard
```

at this point differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference is in the case where `git merge` is not able to fast-forward:

If you have local changes:

`git merge B --ff` fails with an error message:

> ```
> error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
> (list of files)
> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
> Aborting
> ```

`git reset B --hard` silently discards the changes.

If you're mistaken about a fast-forward being possible:

`git merge B --ff` creates a merge commit.

Other than that (and you say those cases do not apply), they both update the current branch (or detached HEAD) exactly the same way: to the exact same commit as `B`.